# how can i search many field name to filter search datagridview in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, search, datagridview

Here's my code

```vb
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from additem where productname like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", con)
```

I want to add fieldnames 'price', 'status', 'category' and 'status'

How can I add those to my code?

Comment: `*` means all column if you want specific column then use those name instead of `*` in `select` statement.

Comment: As @Yogesh mentioned just replace * with column names you want : ` da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select price,status, category,status from additem where productname like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", con)`

Comment: what i am trying to do is this

'da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from additem where [productname], [price], [category], [status] like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", con)'

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause is a Boolean expression.  How do you usually create a compound Boolean expression?  Just like you learned in maths class at school: using AND and OR operators.  It's no different to a Boolean expression in VB code, e.g.

```sql
WHERE productname LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR category LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
```

Note that I have written that using parameters and you should too.  Depending on your provider though, you may not be able to use one parameter in multiple places, so you would have to create multiple parameters with the same value, e.g.

```vb
Dim sql = "SELECT *
           FROM additem
           WHERE productname LIKE '%' + @productname + '%'
           OR category LIKE '%' + @category + '%'"

Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@productname", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
    .Add("@category", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
End With
```

Also note that the `LIKE` operator only works for text values, so it probably doesn't make sense to be searching a column named `price` that same way.  You could convert the price to text in the SQL code but does it really make sense to do a partial search on a currency value?  I'd be inclined to check whether the search text actually is a number and, if so, search for that value specifically, e.g.

```vb
Dim sql = "SELECT *
           FROM additem
           WHERE productname LIKE '%' + @productname + '%'
           OR category LIKE '%' + @category + '%'
           OR (@price1 IS NOT NULL AND price = @price2)"

Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@productname", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
    .Add("@category", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text

    Dim price1Parameter = .Add("@price1", OleDbType.Currency)
    Dim price21Parameter = .Add("@price2", OleDbType.Currency)

    Dim price As Decimal

    If Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, price) Then
        price1Parameter.Value = price
        price2Parameter.Value = price
    Else
        price1Parameter.Value = DBNull.Value
        price2Parameter.Value = DBNull.Value
    End If
End With
```

If you can't use the same parameter in multiple places then you need two parameters for `price`, because you need to do two checks.  Either both parameters will be `NULL` or both will contain the same number.  If they are both `NULL` then that last compound condition doesn't match any record, otherwise it will only match records containing that number.